# Get all TreeItems in an SWT Tree

Tags: java, tree, swt

I want to get an array of all the TreeItems from my SWT Tree. However, the method included in the Tree class, `getItems()` only returns the items that are on the first level of the tree (i.e. that aren't children of anything).

Can someone suggest a way to get all of the children/items?

Answer (score 6):

The documentation of [`Tree#getItems()`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Tree.html#getItems%28%29) is very specific:

> Returns a (possibly empty) array of items contained in the receiver **that are direct item children of the receiver**. These are the roots of the tree.

Here is some sample code that does the trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Tree tree = new Tree(shell, SWT.MULTI);

    TreeItem parentOne = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
    parentOne.setText("Parent 1");
    TreeItem parentTwo = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
    parentTwo.setText("Parent 2");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        TreeItem item = new TreeItem(parentOne, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText(parentOne.getText() + " child " + i);

        item = new TreeItem(parentTwo, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText(parentTwo.getText() + " child " + i);
    }

    parentOne.setExpanded(true);
    parentTwo.setExpanded(true);

    List<TreeItem> allItems = new ArrayList<TreeItem>();

    getAllItems(tree, allItems);

    System.out.println(allItems);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static void getAllItems(Tree tree, List<TreeItem> allItems)
{
    for(TreeItem item : tree.getItems())
    {
        getAllItems(item, allItems);
    }
}

private static void getAllItems(TreeItem currentItem, List<TreeItem> allItems)
{
    TreeItem[] children = currentItem.getItems();

    for(int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
    {
        allItems.add(children[i]);

        getAllItems(children[i], allItems);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but note that the allItems list doesn't include the root elements returned by tree.getItems().

Comment: Note: To achieve it @HennoVermeulen and all, just add `allItems.add(item);` as first statement in the loop inside `#getAllItems(Tree, List<TreeItem>)`.

Comment: @Sumit The code I posted isn't restricted to a particular level. It'll work with an arbitrary number of levels.

Comment: @Baz: Thank you, can you help me in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213400/i-want-to-check-duplicate-treeitem-text-n-number-of-depth-in-the-treeitem-in-s ?

Comment: @Sumit I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question there and already voted to close as "unclear what you're asking" a while ago. If you could rewrite your question and make it more clear what you're trying to do, then maybe people will be able to help. The question, as it stands, isn't clear at all.

Comment: @baz: Did you check above link again?

Comment: @Sumit Yes, and I still don't understand your question. I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: @Baz : How to check/Search Tree-item name  in Tree using traverse function? Can you provide your email ID?

Comment: @Sumit Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I cannot help you and I'm not giving away my email information.