# How to get all row data from multicolumn TreeViewer

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, jface

How to read all the row data from a multicolumn TreeViewer.

[image]

```
m_viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
          @Override
          public void selectionChanged(final SelectionChangedEvent event)
          {
            IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)event.getSelection();

            Object [] selections = selection.toArray();
          }
```

}

This code snippet gives only selected row value. I want to read all the data and save it in an xml file on click of a Save button. Can anyone help me to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by "all"? Did you mean you only have access to the individual cell? Do you have access to the tree viewer's input?

Comment: I see you're new to SO

If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

The objects you get from the structured selection are the objects provided by the content provider for the tree viewer. So you should be able to cast them to whatever class(es) the content provider uses and get the data from them.

This is similar to the objects that are passed to the tree viewer label provider.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a serialize what is close to the visual representation of the tree, you can access the underlying Tree of the TreeViewer and traverse its TreeItems. This approach is described here: [Get all TreeItems in an SWT Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453515/get-all-treeitems-in-jface-tree)

Or you consider to just use the data model that the TreeViewer is showing and serialize its objects. Traversing the children of your data model is presumably already implemented in the content provider, usually a `ITreeContentProvider`, or an extension thereof and could be reused.